# Can I download MULTIPLE youtube search results using youtube-dl?

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl, download-speed

I know how to download the result of one search query but is it possible to download results of more than 1 search queries at once? I was thinking pasting the urls separated by commas.

Answer (score 3):

`youtube-dl` accepts multiple URL's as input, so yes you can download multiple videos with one command: `youtube-dl url1 url2 url3`.

However, if you have *a lot* of urls, consider putting them in a file, each URL on it's own line, and tell youtube-dl to load the URL's from that file: `youtube-dl -a my_url_file.txt`, or the more verbose version: `youtube-dl --batch-file my_url_file.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xargs` to do this. It takes arguments from standard input and adds them to a command. The commands can also be executed in parallel.

Here is an example:

```
echo -n "link1,link2" | xargs -d ',' -n 1 -P 10 youtube-dl
```

This would be roughly equivalent to:

```
youtube-dl link1 &
youtube-dl link2 &
```

Parameters used:

`-d` changes the delimiter for the arguments
`-n` sets the number of arguments to be used for each command
`-P` sets the maximum number of parallel processes